# Use Modelica FMU derivatives in constraint formulation for Pyomo

Tags: pyomo

As per object, I have several models developed in Modelica that I would like to use for optimal control purposes. So, I was wondering if there is any intention of coupling Pyomo with the FMI/FMU standard (in particular with Modelica generated FMU) to enable the extrapolation of derivatives from the FMU for the formulation of constraints, jacobians,etc...

I tried to look into the webpage, blog, newsletters and repository but I did not find anything related.

Comment: DyOS does support FMI, see https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EuMn5ZZtKp0